# How do I disable the double questions to show the 2nd "Vraag 1"(question 1 in English)

Tags: php, select

I have answers to questions in a database and when I show them it shows the question and the amount of times a choice is chosen. The thing is that I want to group the choices by the questions so I don't have the same question 4 times when there are 4 choices. I think it has to do with the way I echo them but I couldn't think of a way to fix this.

I tried changing the echo a bit but nu success.

```
$Yeet = "SELECT count(answer_id) FROM survey_answers";
$Yeetres = mysqli_query($conn, $Yeet);
if ($Yeetres ->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Yeetres)) {

        $aantal = $row['count(answer_id)'];
        for ($meme = 1; $meme <= $aantal; $meme++) {
        $countAnswerQuery = "SELECT answer_id, COUNT(*), question_id  FROM survey_answers WHERE question_id = '$meme' GROUP BY answer_id ORDER BY question_id ASC";
        $countanswerresult = mysqli_query($conn, $countAnswerQuery);
        if ($countanswerresult ->num_rows > 0) {
          while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($countanswerresult)) {

            $question = $row['question_id'];
            $answer = $row['answer_id'];
            $count = $row['COUNT(*)'];

            $value = "SELECT answer_id, answer FROM survey_question_answers";
            $valueresult = mysqli_query($conn, $value);
            if ($valueresult ->num_rows > 0) {
              while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($valueresult)) {
                $answervalue = $row['answer_id'];
                $echt = $row['answer'];
          //changes the answer ( that atm is a number ) to its actual value
                if($answervalue == $answer){
                  $answer = $echt;            

                  echo "Vraag " . $question. "<br>";
                  echo "Keuze: <b>". $answer . "</b> is " .$count ." keer ingevuld ";

                  echo "<form method='POST'><input type='hidden' name='id' value='$question'>";
                  echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show answer" class="btn btn-primary mb-3 mt-3"></form><br><br> ';

                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }
```

I hope to be able to have the questions and the choices grouped.
This is what it echo's currently:

[image: currentPage]

And this is the database:

[image: Data]

Comment: You want to implement what’s called a [control break](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break). Your data needs to be sorted appropriately (by question first), and then in your output loop you simply compare the question of the current record with that of the previous one - only if they differ, you output the question, if they are still the same, you output only the current answer.

Comment: And how to do thtat

Comment: Well the way I just described it …? What exactly are you having problems understanding?

Comment: I get it but i dont know how I can make this in php...

Comment: Sorry, but that is just too unspecific to get any specific response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check inside your iteration if the current question is the same as the previous question. If they are not the same, then echo the actual question. Like @04FS said. Use that question as the Control Break.

Simplified code:

```
$_prevQuestion = null; $_currQuestion = null;
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($valueresult)) {

        $_currQuestion = $question;

        ...

        if($answervalue == $answer){

           ...

          // check if new question or not, if so, echo the question
          if ($_currQuestion !== $_prevQuestion) {
            echo "Vraag " . $question. "<br>";
          }
          echo "Keuze: <b>". $answer . "</b> is " .$count ." keer ingevuld ";

          ...

        }

        $_prevQuestion = $question;
      }
```

Comment: @Yalikejazz I just stripped some of the code that was unrelated to your question/the answer.

Comment: Ok but now it also not shows the choice and amount of times its answered. So it works but to good. And it only shows question 1

Comment: It could be me being braindead but I can't get it to work properly. It keeps deleting the first answer and question.